# Access VBA Passing a Variable between modules

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two modules. One runs a procedure (various queries, etc) and the other one is supposed to write to a table, such as the Username, changes made, etc.

I've successfully written a script that writes to a table and one that reads from the table. However, I cannot pass that variable from one to the other.

For example, here is the code that is trying to read a "User" value from the sub/function `ReadSystemTbl()`

```
Sub Testing()

  Dim x As String

  x = ReadSystemTbl("User")

  MsgBox x

End Sub
```

And here is the code that finds the value and returns it:

```
Public Function ReadSystemTbl(FindField As String)

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim SystemField As Field, SystemValue As Field
Dim results As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SystemTbl")
Set SystemField = rs.Fields("SystemField")
Set SystemValue = rs.Fields("SystemValue")

Do Until rs.EOF
 If SystemField = FindField Then
    results = SystemValue
 End If
 rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Consider adding `Exit Function` before `End If`, so you don't iterate the whole recordset if you don't need to. Actually.. don't. Make your code work, and put it up on [codereview.se] to get feedback about properly cleaning up resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are just missing

```
ReadSystemTbl = results
```

in the ReadSystemTbl function.